# Combine Multiple Order Rows into 1 Row per Order, max of 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2016

Issue: I receive a flat file from our web order system. I need to import this data to our internal mail order system. The web order file contains 1 row per order per item. So if 12 items where ordered, there would be 12 rows with the same order ID. I need to convert this so the line items are on the same row. The caveat of this is that there can only be a max of 5 line items per row, per order. So the 12 items ordered need to become 3 lines. At the end of lines 1 and 2, there needs to be a continuation flag stating the order continues on the next line.

Sample of Web order file:

[Web Order Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLK4H.png)

```
SAMPLE# Row orderid ocustomerid odate   ofirstname  customer_pmntprofileid itemid   numitems    unitprice   itemamount
1   1   171476  5230    11/14/2018  Scott   1324426745  R22046  1   269.95  269.95
1   2   171476  5230    11/14/2018  Scott   1324426745  R81100  12  7.5 90
3   1   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF49972 6   39.95   239.7
3   2   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF49973 4   39.95   159.8
3   3   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF47970 1   43.95   43.95
3   4   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44090 1   43.95   43.95
3   5   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44091 1   43.95   43.95
3   6   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44092 1   43.95   43.95
3   7   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44093 1   43.95   43.95
3   8   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44094 1   43.95   43.95
3   9   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44114 1   50.95   50.95
3   10  171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44139 1   46.95   46.95
3   11  171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44138 1   46.95   46.95
3   12  171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44066 1   43.95   43.95
4   1   171702  6120    11/14/2018  Tim 1382791806  L81313  5   17.95   89.75
4   2   171702  6120    11/14/2018  Tim 1382791806  L81314  1   30.95   30.95
4   3   171702  6120    11/14/2018  Tim 1382791806  L82039  6   8.95    53.7
4   4   171702  6120    11/14/2018  Tim 1382791806  L82013  1   69.95   69.95
```

I need to turn sample 1 into 1 row, sample 3 into 3 rows and sample 4 into 1 row.
Output needed:

[Order Import Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b05Re.png)

```
SAMPLE #    orderid ocustomerid odate   ofirstname  customer_pmntprofileid  ITEM_ID1    QTY1    PRICE1  AMOUNT1 ITEM_ID2    QTY2    PRICE2  AMOUNT2 ITEM_ID3    QTY3    PRICE3  AMOUNT3 ITEM_ID4    QTY4    PRICE4  AMOUNT4 ITEM_ID5    QTY5    PRICE5  AMOUNT5 Continue
1   171476  5230    11/14/2018  Scott   1324426745  R22046  1   269.95  269.95  R81100  12  7.5 90                                                  N
3   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF49972 6   39.95   239.7   AF49973 4   39.95   159.8   AF47970 1   43.95   43.95   AF44090 1   43.95   43.95   AF44091 1   43.95   43.95   Y
3   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44092 1   43.95   43.95   AF44093 1   43.95   43.95   AF44094 1   43.95   43.95   AF44114 1   50.95   50.95   AF44139 1   46.95   46.95   Y
3   171690  6119    11/14/2018  Joe 1382758196  AF44138 1   46.95   46.95   AF44066 1   43.95   43.95                                                   N
4   171702  6120    11/14/2018  Tim 1382791806  L81313  5   17.95   89.75   L81314  1   30.95   30.95   L82039  6   8.95    53.7    L82013  1   69.95   69.95                   N
5   171706  70  11/14/2018  Bruce   1382821080  L84264  1   584.99  584.99  L84409  1   584.99  584.99  L84410  1   584.99  584.99  L84633  1   539.99  539.99  L84634  1   539.99  539.99  Y
```

Comment: Can you please give some sample data with insert statements.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in your database?  It's better to do it in your display layer.

Comment: IMHO this is a bad design. Original flat file version is much better.

Comment: I completely agree that the design is bad. Unfortunately, it's what I have to work with. The alternative, is that the end user has to key in the web orders by hand.

Comment: Whoever came up with the design should be forced to do this import then, until they see the error of their ways.   : )

Comment: If you have to live with that, then import to a temp table, add row_number partitioning by orderid. You could use row_number % 5 +1 as their respective column numbers.

Comment: BTW, for someone to help you using your data as test, please format it so that it could be easily converted to a table. The web order version doesn't really look like this. It looks like it is a table (HTML) which could easily be read by, say, Excel. And, does this need to be done purely with T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select SAMPLE, orderid, ocustomerid, odate, ofirstname, customer_pmntprofileid,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 1 then itemid end) as itemid_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 1 then numitems end) as numitems_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 1 then unitprice end) as unitprice_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 1 then itemamount end) as itemamount_1,  
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 2 then itemid end) as itemid_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 2 then numitems end) as numitems_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 2 then unitprice end) as unitprice_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 2 then itemamount end) as itemamount_2,  
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 3 then itemid end) as itemid_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 3 then numitems end) as numitems_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 3 then unitprice end) as unitprice_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 3 then itemamount end) as itemamount_1,  
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 4 then itemid end) as itemid_4,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 4 then numitems end) as numitems_4,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 4 then unitprice end) as unitprice_4,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 4 then itemamount end) as itemamount_4,  
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 0 then itemid end) as itemid_5,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 0 then numitems end) as numitems_5,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 0 then unitprice end) as unitprice_5,
       max(case when seqnum % 5 = 0 then itemamount end) as itemamount_5,
       (case when max(seqnum) < max(cnt) then 'Y' else 'N' end) as continuation_flag 
from (select wo.*,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid order by row) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid) as cnt
      from web_orders wo
     ) wo
group by SAMPLE, orderid, ocustomerid, odate, ofirstname, customer_pmntprofileid,
         (seqnum - 1) / 5;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give these a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
WITH 
t1 AS (select * FROM mytable WHERE row % 5 = 1),
t2 AS (select * FROM mytable WHERE row % 5 = 2),
t3 AS (select * FROM mytable WHERE row % 5 = 3),
t4 AS (select * FROM mytable WHERE row % 5 = 4),
t5 AS (select * FROM mytable WHERE row % 5 = 0)
SELECT t1.SAMPLE,
       ceiling(t1.Row/5.0) AS Row,
       t1.orderid,
       t1.ocustomerid,
       t1.odate,
       t1.ofirstname,
       t1.customer_pmntprofileid,
       t1.itemid AS itemid1,
       t1.numitems AS numitems1,
       t1.unitprice AS unitprice1,
       t1.itemamount AS itemAmount1,
       t2.itemid AS itemId2,
       t2.numitems AS numitems2,
       t2.unitprice AS unitprice2,
       t2.itemamount AS itemamount2,
       t3.itemid AS itemId3,
       t3.numitems AS numitems3,
       t3.unitprice AS unitprice3,
       t3.itemamount AS itemamount3,
       t4.itemid AS itemId4,
       t4.numitems AS numitems4,
       t4.unitprice AS unitprice4,
       t4.itemamount AS itemamount4,
       t5.itemid AS itemId5,
       t5.numitems AS numitems5,
       t5.unitprice AS unitprice5,
       t5.itemamount AS itemamount5
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.orderid = t2.orderid AND CEILING(t1.row/5.0)=ceiling(t2.row/5.0)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.orderid = t3.orderid AND CEILING(t1.row/5.0)=ceiling(t3.row/5.0)
LEFT JOIN t4 ON t1.orderid = t4.orderid AND CEILING(t1.row/5.0)=ceiling(t4.row/5.0)
LEFT JOIN t5 ON t1.orderid = t5.orderid AND CEILING(t1.row/5.0)=ceiling(t5.row/5.0);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e4267fe9980ad5adcb3f9b12a6e5a67)

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try and let you know!